# How to successfully show an image with Pillow in Python?

Tags: python

I used the Pillow library to show an image (called 'beach_sky.jpg'), but when I use the show() function, nothing happens! I read that a utility called 'xv' is necessary... I'm using an Android device by the way. Here's the code :

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('beach_sky.jpg')
img.show()
```

Terminal output:

```
"""
WARNING: linker: _imaging.cpython-36m.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x45ec
WARNING: linker: _imaging.cpython-36m.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x1

[Program finished]
"""
```

Can you help me somehow showing the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
image = Image.open("<b>image path</b>")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = Label(root, image=render)
label.image = render

label.pack()

root.mainloop()
#Simple Enough
```

Comment: Ok, I know the "image path", but what about "image" and "render", what should I put there?

Comment: But when I try to pip install it, an error occurs! It isn't existing?